# Crash recovery of c++ coroutine

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine, c++-coroutine

If an application crashes while a coroutine is running, is it possible to recover the coroutine state after crash ? In other words, can we save coroutine state (or coroutine handle) on disk (on specific points in our application) and load all the coroutine-states when the application restarts due to a crash ? I want to resume a coroutine handle after crash.

[image]

I am trying to investigate the feasibility of coroutine for an existing toy application. The application restarts after crash and loads the in memory states (Or state machine) from a file system supported by disk.

Comment: How a coroutine works is an implementation detail of the runtime/platform.

Comment: @Raildex, sure. But resuming from crash is a required feature for a crash consistent application. Also one of the promising application of c++ coroutine is avoiding callback chain in a state machine business logic.
So, my point is, to understand how can I make, coroutine usable in a crash consistent application.

Comment: a crash is something that should not occur in the first place

Comment: I don't think there is a way to recover process except a tailor-made version by using memento pattern or something else. If you know it would happen, then *don't* let it happen.

Comment: Question might probably be rewritten as *"can we serialize/deserialize coroutine?"* And I would say generically no, but some might have those capability.

Comment: @Raildex, yes true, ideally. But in a distributed system consisting of many nodes, crash is a norm not an exception.

Comment: @Debashish crashes should never happen. They do when we screw up, but a production system should almost never crash. A crash means you’ve invoked undefined behavior and so all bets are off about everything that can happen, will happen, and has already happened. So if you have a crash, the standard offers no guarantee that a saved state earlier in the run is even valid.

Comment: @Ben, I agree, it should not happen. But there are systems which need fault tolerance, ( https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2482856 )
-- I am just asking, can we save & load coroutine, by some workaround, I don't mean to have a standard guarantee.

Comment: @Debashish I did not find the article you post mentioned about crash. Though I agree slow down and timeout might be hard to reproduce and debug. Please let me know if I missed any point in the article.

Comment: @Jarod42 I guess if no pointers/references are stored on the stack, it might be possible :) Could be a case for using array indices.

Comment: Looks like temporal https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-18XztyN6c has solution this serialization issue. Although on in C++.